# How to return data from html tag in scrapy

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I need to extract data from html tags have class is `class="review card"`

My HTML source is

```
<session class="full-reviews">
  <div class="feature-reviews"> 
    <div class="review card"></div>
    <div class="review card"></div>
    <div class="review card"></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="review card></div>
  <div class="review card"></div>
</session>
```

How I can select only html tag have class `review card` outside class `feature-reviews`

Answer (score 1):

One possible way with XPath:

```
//session[@class="full-reviews"]/div[@class="review card"]
```

Comment: Or CSS: `.full-reviews > .review` (skipping `.card` assuming it’s not needed here)